# pydantic BaseModel not found in Fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I have [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) 3.6.9 on Kubuntu 18.04. I have installed [fastapi](/questions/tagged/fastapi) using `pip3 install fastapi`. I'm trying to test drive the framework through its official documentation and I'm in [the relational database section](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/) of its guide.

In `schemas.py`:

```
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel

class VerseBase(BaseModel):
    AyahText: str
    NormalText: str

class Verse(VerseBase):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

VS code highlights an error in `from pydantic import BaseModel` and it tells that: `No name 'BaseModel' in module 'pydantic'`. Additionally, when I try to run `uvicorn main:app reload`  I have gotten the following error:

> ```
> File "./main.py", line 6, in <module>
>    from . import crud, models, schemas
> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
> ```

I have tried to renstall `pydantic` using `pip3` but it tells me that:

```
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses>=0.6; python_version < "3.7" in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pydantic) (0.7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of highlighting in VS code may be a problem due to the fact that you did not open the folder. It's quite annoying as it happens often to me as well (and I have basically your same config).

Regarding the second problem you mention, it is probably due to the fact that the folder in which the script lays, does not have a `__init__.py` file. If you add it, it should work since python will interpret the folder as a module.

As an alternative, you could try to import with the full path from the top folder (e.g. `from app.module.main import app`).

For more information about modules see the following links:

[Python 3.8 Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

[Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/)

Comment: I  have noticed something, when importing it from the project's root, the import works as regarded in the tutorial, but if I have tried to run it from the `myprojectRoot/db`, I have to modify the import statements

Comment: Without the folder structure it's not easy for me to provide an answer, but that's how python imports work (or at least I understand for your project structure)

Answer (score 17):

This is a common problem with binary/C extensions. For further details, check here: ([Pylint & C extensions](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/c_extensions.html))

To fix it, you need to add the following to .pylintrc file (You can add this file to your current project folder if you like)

```
[MASTER]
extension-pkg-allow-list=pydantic
```

Note that switching to mypy (as suggested by another answer here) is *not* the right approach since pylint & mypy are two different things (the former is a *linter* while the latter is sort of a *type checker*)

Answer (score 6):

The first thing that you noticed

> pydantic BaseModel not found in Fastapi

is related to your linter.
I got the same warning when my linter was `pylint`, so I changed the linter from `pylint` to `mypy` and the problem disappeared.

1. Install mypy via pip

   `pip install mypy`
2. Open the command palette in VScode

   `Ctrl+Shift+P`
3. Type this in command palett:

   `Python: Select Linter`
4. Then Select `mypy` in the list of linters

Comment: This suggestion worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

Tested on vscode:

In your workspace folder, specify Options in

> pylintrc

or

> .pylintrc

options file, as specified in [Pylint command line argument](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options), using this command: `pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc`

Look for `extension-pkg-allow-list` and add `pydantic` after `=`
It should be like this after generating the options file: `extension-pkg-allow-list=`

When you add pydantic, it should be like this:

```
extension-pkg-allow-list=pydantic
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the excellent answers that explain how to modify `.pylintrc`, if you are using `pyproject.toml` for your project you can do this instead:

```
[tool.pylint.main]
extension-pkg-allow-list = ["pydantic"]
```

Comment: And in `.pylintrc`, you can use
`extension-pkg-allow-list=pydantic`, see [documentation](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v2.17.2/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#extension-pkg-allow-list)